# How to use javascript in my laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php

I've(admin) to approve a driver request for that i'm using javascript code to display the status of driver  which 'ld change on click of the image(approved/unapproved).It doesn't access the javascript code.Here is script in blade file,

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
$(".plus").click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass("minus")  ; 
})
.plus{
background-image: 
 url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/
icons/ie_Bright/128/plus_add_blue.png");
width:130px;
height:130px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.plus.minus{
background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons
/ie_Bright/128/plus_add_minus.png");
width:130px;
height:130px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }
</script>
```

My code,

```
<div class="plus"><a href="{!! route('approve', ['id' => $user->id]) 
 !!}">Approve</a></div>


`@push('scripts')

 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 @endpush
```

Comment: Why do you have css inside a `script` tag?

Comment: @Jackowski But one more question that how should I write code to change the db field value "approved='1'" on click of the image and on when another click "approved='0'"